# Marshmallow Nested Serializer KeyError: u'Manager'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, marshmallow

I'm using Marshmallow's nested serializers and getting the error "KeyError: u'manager'".

Here are my serializers:

```
class ShiftSerializer(Schema):

    agent = fields.String()
    date = fields.String()
    end = fields.String()
    status = fields.String()

class KPIShiftSerializer(Schema):

    interval = fields.DateTime()
    incoming = fields.Integer()
    duration = fields.Decimal()
    shifts_future = fields.Nested(ShiftSerializer, many=True)
    shifts_current = fields.Nested(ShiftSerializer, many=True)
    shifts_ending = fields.Nested(ShiftSerializer, many=True)
```

And my models:

```
class Shift(models.Model):

    agent = models.CharField(default=" ", max_length=200)
    date = models.CharField(default='01/01/1900', max_length=10)
    end = models.DateTimeField(default=utc.localize(datetime(1900,1,1)))
    status = models.CharField(default='Available', max_length=200)

class KPI(models.Model):

    interval = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    incoming = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    duration = models.FloatField(default=0)
    shifts_future = models.ManyToManyField(Shift, related_name="returning")
    shifts_current = models.ManyToManyField(Shift, related_name="staffed")
    shifts_ending = models.ManyToManyField(Shift, related_name="leaving")
```

Comment: Can you share additional information? What do the models look like?

Comment: of course!  just edited

Comment: I'm not sure the error is coming from this snippet. I don't see anything in the code you provided that would cause this issue. Is there a longer stack trace you could share?

Comment: @Lee, were you able to find the solution?